# Java doesn't return function value as supposed to

Tags: java

The following code is part of my program, not all of it. In lasTal(), I let the user enter numbers in a number sequence. Once the user is done, he is supposed to press enter so that my program reacts on the empty string entered and returns the list of numbers.

```
public class Nastaord{
    public static int bFinal, cFinal;
    public static ArrayList<Integer> tallistaFinal;

    private static ArrayList<Integer> lasTal(){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer> tallista = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //Det vi ska ha talföljden i

        int i = 0;  //räknare för tallista
        while(true){
            System.out.print("Enter number, or press enter if you are done: ");
            String input = scanner.nextLine();
            if(input == ""){
                return tallista;}
            int nytt_tal = Integer.parseInt(input);
            tallista.add(nytt_tal);
            i++;
        }
```

I get the following runtime error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at Nastaord.lasTal(Nastaord.java:18)
    at Nastaord.main(Nastaord.java:45)
```

it seems to me that the program never enters the if-statement for the empty string, and instead tries to convert the string "" to an int, which is impossible. Why is this and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try `"".equals(input)` instead of `input == ""`.